# How to add link to objects property value?

Tags: vuejs2

Please suggest a way for me to add link/anchor tag to the value of objects property in vue.js.
I.e. I want the word journey in the title property to have a link. Coudn't able to find a solution since I am new to vue.

My template:

```
 <blog-post v-bind="post"></blog-post>
```

Vue Script:

```
  post: {
     id: 1,
     title: 'My Journey with Vue'
   }
```

Answer (score -1):

You can inject HTML code into an HTML component with:

```
post: {
  id: 1,
  title: 'My <a href="#">Journey</a> with Vue'
}

<span v-html="post.title"></span>
```

But, this method is dangerous because, if the post title value comes from an unreliable source, like an user input, it can lead to becoming the cause of possible XSS attacks.

**Use `v-html` carefully.**